# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have error when i want to update in database.

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\unija\aids\admin\project.php:85 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\unija\aids\admin\project.php(85):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\unija\aids\admin\project.php on line 85

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('UPDATE Projekti SET NaslovSrpski=:naslovs, NaslovEngleski=:naslove, Nosilac=:nosilac, Partneri=:part, Teritorija=:ter, Vrednost=:vrednost, Donator=:donator, TrajanjeOD=:trajanjeod, TrajanjeDO=:trajanjedo, TekstSrpski=:teksts, TekstEngleski=:tekste, Slika=:upic WHERE ID=:uid');
      $stmt->bindParam(':naslovs',$NaslovSrpski);
      $stmt->bindParam(':naslove',$NaslovEngleski);
      $stmt->bindParam(':nosilac',$Nosilac);
      $stmt->bindParam(':part',$Partneri);
      $stmt->bindParam(':ter',$Teritorija);
      $stmt->bindParam(':vrednost',$Vrednost);
      $stmt->bindParam(':donator',$Donator);
      $stmt->bindParam(':trajanjeod',$TrajanjeOD);
      $stmt->bindParam(':trajanjedo',$TrajanjeDO);
      $stmt->bindParam(':teksts',$TekstSrpski);
      $stmt->bindParam(':tekste',$TekstEngleski);
      $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);

   if($stmt->execute())
      {
        $successMSG = "Uspesno ste dodali projekat!";
        header("index.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
      }
      else
      {
        $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
      }
```

Full code here: http://gamers.rs/php.txt

Comment: Just as the error mentiones `Invalid parameter number` and as mentioned in the answer of @Greenkiller you're missing a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You forget one bind :

```
$stmt->bindParam(':uid',$id);
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: man I think it still doesn't work because he called the id $id, edit your reply !

Comment: No he call `WHERE ID = :uid` so he must bind with a var with a variable. He just forget to make a bind

Comment: yes but the value is in $id.

Comment: Oh sorry I have just misunderstood. I'll edit this post.